# bind dropdownlist in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have this Javascript code for a dropdown list

```
 $('#TravelG').append("<option value selected>Select TravelG</option>");
    for (var i = 0; i < Travel.length; i++) {
        $('#TravelG').append("<option value='" +
 Travel[i].Id + "'>" + Travel[i].Name + "</option>");
    }
```

I need to rewrite the above code in knockout as in I have this observable array,

```
viewModel.Travelname = ko.observableArray([]);
```

I need to populate this Travelname property of viewmodel as name , value pair and Travel is the object that contains the data. So that I can tie this Travelname property of a viewmodel to a dropdown. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you looked into the `options` binding? You would end up with something like `<select data-bind="options: Travelname">`. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned in comments by @hunch_hunch, you should use knockout [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for this.

Suppose your `Travel` model looks like this:

```
function Travel(id, name) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
}
```

Then in your view model you have your `observableArray` with collection of `Travel` objects (`this` refers to view model):

```
this.Travelname = ko.observableArray([new Travel(1, 'Moscow'), new Travel(2, 'Paris'), new Travel(3, 'San Francisco')]);
```

The final part is your markup, which should be something like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: Travelname, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select travel...'"></select>
```

Here is final working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w03xgujs/1/). I've added simple functionality to add items to the list, so you would see how to do that.